# Google Signin API called even button is not pressed?

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I tried to implement google sign in api, but every time I opened the app, even I didnt click sign in button, button click is called in the code and throw exception that in if (result.isSuccess()) that result is null, anyone knows why?

```
 public class Login extends FragmentActivity {

         private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 2222;
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                       .requestEmail()
                                       .build();
              mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                 .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                                 .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                                 .build();           
              google_Button = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
              google_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


        public void onClick(View v) {
                 switch (v.getId()) {
                     case R.id.sign_in_button:
                     Log.d("Result: ","click google");
                     signIn();
                     break;

        }
    }


         private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Log.d("Result: ","google sign in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }

    }


        private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
              Log.d("Google token: ",result.getSignInAccount().getEmail());
        } else {            
            Log.d("Google","fail");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onDestroy()` or `onStop()` method call this :

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
```

This is because sometimes the api client is not destroyed and the session has still not finished.
If you want to logout then use the following code on click of your logout button.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

   Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);

   Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
       .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
        }
        });
   mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```